# Trying to deploy react app on aws amplify but keep getting a "Base Directory not specified for artifacts, unable to create build artifact."

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, containers, aws-amplify

My react app is not making it past the build section. I was able to some some of the previous errors, but I am stuck on this one:  `2021-10-03T20:15:39.408Z [ERROR]: !!! CustomerError: Base Directory not specified for artifacts, unable to create build artifact..`

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpNGs.png)

This are my build settings, the amplify.yml file. Does anyone know how I can fix this error?

```
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
        - amplifyPush --simple
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - node -v
        - npm run-script build
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Answer (score 5):

This happens cause there is no entry for `artifacts`, which holds `baseDirectory` and `files`, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.artifacts.

```yaml
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - node -v
        - npm run-script build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```